# Ruby on Rails Permission denied - /root/.bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to install teambox on ruby. I am running passenger and getting this error:

Permission denied - /root/.bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications

I tried the following 
chown teambox directory to teambox user 
chown /root/.bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications to teambox user.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution would be pass a custom shared path to bundle, so instead of doing

```
bundle install
```

you could do

```
bundle install shared_path
```

where shared_path is a directory with correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Login as the teambox user and run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my `bundle install` command.  Mine was caused because earlier I had mistyped a help command.  Bad => `bundle install /?`

Here's the error:

```
/Users/wee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir':     Permission denied - /? (Errno::EACCES)
from /Users/wee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in  `fu_mkdir'
from /Users/wee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
```

I was able to fix my issue by adding the current directory to the command: `bundle install .`.